# Database Design for Messaging in Facebook

Tags: database-design, facebook

I'm currently working on creating a messaging system similar to Facebook.  More specifically, the private messages on Facebook-- complete with an Inbox, Sent Messages, "Unread" and "Read."

Is anyone familiar with a similar database structure to what Facebook currently uses for their messaging system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is something you might find useful to start off :

Start with 2 tables, one that will contain the actual message, and one you will use to keep track of the relationship between messages

That could be something like this :

```
private_messages tbl:
id
date_sent
title
content
status ENUM ('unread', 'read') DEFAULT 'unread'

private_message_relation tbl:
id
message_id
sender_id
receiver_id
```

Then you may want to add constraints to the ids of the relation tbl for data integrity purposes.

Comment: What if someone flags the comment when he/she sees the subject line, but hasn't read the message? Or what if he/she reads it, then flags it? IMHO, "read" and "flagged" should be independent booleans.

Comment: I believe this may depends on you're implementation. I edited and removed it from the status field to make things stay simple. However, I believe this can stil work if you don't let users flag a message till it's not opened, or if you consider that if a message is flagged, it has been red.

Comment: if User A deletes the messages i want the User B to still have a copy of it. how can i do that with this ?

Comment: What if I use only one table with fields -> id, sender_id, receiver_id, message,status, date. Isn't it same. I think joining table would be slower and it would be nice to structure in same table.

Answer (score 4):

As a correction to Joe's comment, Facebook uses Cassandra to power inbox search, not messaging. And that "reverse engineering" is of the Facebook platform's object classes, which I don't think gives a very representative look at the database design at all.

Answer (score 1):

The approach below should be able to sort you out. This is a good basis for both chat and messaging, where with chat you can poll recent messages from the client side and slap on an intuitive UI.

```
Message {
  MessageId,
  SenderId, -- Foreign key User.UserId  
  DateSent,
  Subject, 
  Content,
  Attachment, -- can be null or default to a 0
  ...
}

UserMessage {
  Id, 
  MessageId, -- Foreign key Message.MessagId
  RecepientId, -- Foreign key User.UserId
  DateRead -- can default to year 1900 if you do not want to deal with nulls
}

User {
  UserId
  UserName
  ...
}

Queries    

Read = UserMessage where DateRead > year 1900 (or not equal to null)
Inbox = UserMessage where RecepientId = Me.UserId
Sent = Message where SenderId = Me.UserId
Conversation = Group by Subject
Attachment = (Simple = Path to attachment file. || Better = DocumentId ... see below)

Attachment

Document {
  int DocumentId,
  int DocTypeId,
  virtual DocumentType DocumentType,
  string FileName,
  int UserId,
  string mimeType,
  float fileSize,
  string storagePath,
  int OrganizationId,
  string fileHash,
  string ipAddress,
  DateTime DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook is using a completely custom system that does not use a traditional "Database" at all.  That said, this guy did reverse engineer what a schema would look like: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/06/02/3124.aspx

It turns out they are using something called [Casandra](http://highscalability.com/product-facebooks-cassandra-massive-distributed-store).  You can go to the [google code project directly](http://code.google.com/p/the-cassandra-project/) as well (link is down for me).  The short of it is that they use something like Google's BigTable and not MySQL.

EDIT: See Josh Smith's post above for a correction on this post.

Comment: how can we implement this in MySQL ?